# Configurable Hibernate enum Converter through Spring property?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, enums

How to create a configurable Hibernate converter to convert Java enum values to db values. I want to make this configurable through a spring property to indicate if the enum value should be converted to a DB String value or a DB integer (the enum ordinal value).
I want it to be configurable such that it is backwards compatible, that is: when not configured, it is converted to an integer value, and through the spring property I can change that to db String values. The converter will be part of a shared external Java library that is used by several of my projects.

I tried several things, and it seemed much harder than I thought.

What I came up with is having 2 Converter, 1 for the integer and 1 for the string, and adding it to hibernate through a MetadataBuilderContributor.

The converters:

```
public class ServerLogTypeDbConverter implements AttributeConverter<ServerlogEntryType, String> {
    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(ServerlogEntryType attribute) {
        return attribute.name();
    }

    @Override
    public ServerlogEntryType convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        return ServerlogEntryType.valueOf(dbData);
    }
}
```

```
public class ServerLogTypeDbConverter implements AttributeConverter<ServerlogEntryType, Integer> {
    @Override
    public Integer convertToDatabaseColumn(ServerlogEntryType attribute) {
        return attribute.ordinal();
    }

    @Override
    public ServerlogEntryType convertToEntityAttribute(Integer dbData) {
        return ServerlogEntryType.values()[ordinal];
    }
}
```

Then the challenge is to register one of these Hibernate converters, depending on the spring property, such that they are picked up. Through several posts in SO I came up with the following: when the spring-boot application starts, get informed before any bean is created, read the property, and then add a hibernate property that will use a hibernate MetadataBuilderContributor to add the converter, below the code snippets:

```
public class MetadataBuilderContributerResolver implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent> {
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent event) {
        var environment = event.getEnvironment();
        var testValue = environment.getProperty("bla.test");

        Class<?> metadataBuilderContributorClazz = switch (testValue) {
            case "string" -> AttributeConverterMetadataBuilderContributor.class;
            default -> throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported builder: " + testValue);
        };

        var className = metadataBuilderContributorClazz.getName();

        var props = new Properties();
        props.put("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.metadata_builder_contributor", className);
        environment.getPropertySources().addFirst(new PropertiesPropertySource(this.getClass().getName(), props));
    }
}
```

And:

```
public class AttributeConverterMetadataBuilderContributor implements MetadataBuilderContributor {
    @Override
    public void contribute(MetadataBuilder metadataBuilder) {
        metadataBuilder.applyAttributeConverter(ServerLogTypeDbConverter.class);
    }
}
```

This works, but has 2 major downsides:

- The Spring listener has to be added by code to the Spring boot application (annotations are read by a Spring bean and they do not exist yet). This is difficult in an external lib where this converter will be contained.
- The interface MetadataBuilderContributor is deprecated. I read that I need to use the FunctionContributor, but no idea how ...

Please some advice, as I am a bit stuck now